# JsonModelLib: Unable to parse if a variable does not exists in JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, jsonmodel

I know my question is a little confusing so please allow me to elaborate.

JSON Parsing Lib : [JSONModelLib](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/JSONModel/JSONModelLib.h)

**MODEL**

```
#import "JsonModelLib/JSONModel.h"


@interface CustomerDetailsModel : JSONModel


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *activatedTill;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *birthdate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *phone;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *id;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *statusCode;

@end
```

**JSON string**

```
NSString* str = @"\
{\
\"description\": \"None\",\
\"firstName\": \"vikas\",\
\"lastName\": \"bansal\",\
\"activatedTill\": \"2016-01-17 09:04:11\",\
\"email\": \"bansal\",\
\"birthdate\": \"None\",\
\"phone\": \"None\",\
\"id\": \"1053\",\
\"statusCode\": \"1600\"\
}\
";
```

**Parsing**

```
CustomerDetailsModel* c = [[CustomerDetailsModel alloc] initWithString:str error:nil];
```

**PROBLEM**

The problem is that some time when json does not contain a variable that exists in MODEL **Why??** becuase the REST API I am using does not render variable into JSON if there is no value in it.

For an example suppose there is no value in birthdate then it will not be included in JSON so when I will try to parse the JSON what I will get is an error.

**Please help or please suggest what should I do**

Note: I have already gone far ahead with **JsonModelLib** so if you asking me to use something else or some other lib then I will be a great pain for me. Please please please try to suggest something without changing the lib if it is possible

Many many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an optional model property - there's an example in the repo's README.
https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel#optional-properties-ie-can-be-missing-or-null

Comment: you just saved my life. Thank you so much @Marin Todorov